# rust Массив, состоящий из кортежей

Tags: rust

Я начал учить rust, до этого знал только python. И поскольку эти языки кардинально отличаются, у меня появилось множество проблем уже сейчас. Одна из которых - это создание массива заполненного кортежами.
Как мне это реализовать, желательно с объяснениями.

Comment: Массива или вектора?

Comment: в чём именно проблема? создать массив кортежей просто — `let foo = [(12,"qwe"),(3,"asd")];`.

Comment: я не знаю, массив или вектор... Грубо говоря аналог списка из Python (схожее).

Comment: Мне нужно понять, как передавать массив (или вектор) заполненный кортежами, как аргумент функции

Comment: @DimaTyapkin, если это не праздное желание от того, что одним замечательным утром ты решил «а не передать ли мне сегодня массив кортежей в функцию», то для чего это всё... добавь пример, чего именно ты хочешь с рациональным образованием (помни про «проблему XY»)... «передать массив в функцию» в rust нельзя, можно передать ссылку на массив, вектор, копию вектора, ссылку на вектор, но посоветовать тебе что-то одно без описания проблемы сложно, а перечислять всё это разнообразия и различия между ними, когда вопрос не об этом нет особого желание... ЗЫ: при ответах используй упоминание через `@`…

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример с массивом и вектором:

```rust
const N: usize = 3;

fn f(_: &[(isize, isize); N]) {}

fn g(_: &std::vec::Vec<(isize, isize)>) {}

fn main() {
    let a = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)];
    f(&a);

    let v = vec![(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)];
    g(&v);
}
```